# Redirect to /admin/login/ results in 302

Tags: django

I'm trying to redirect to the login page when a user is not authenticated. In my `settings.py` class I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'path.to.AuthRequiredMiddleware',
]
```

Here is my class:

```
class AuthRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/login/')
        return None
```

However this always results in `[24/Jan/2017 14:09:07] "GET /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` when the user is not authenticated, does anyone know how to fix this? Changing the redirection URL results in the same issue no matter what it is.

I have also tried to use the `django.shortcuts import redirect` however I got the same `302` result as well from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your whole code then you always end up in a redirect loop.

1. user is not logged in and goes to `/`
2. user is redirected to `/admin/login` since there should be a login form
3. user lands on `/admin/login` but is still not logged in, gets redirected to `/admin/login`
4. repeat step 3. indefinitely

So `/admin/login` should be an exception where user can get when he is not logged in.

Something like this:

```
class AuthRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        redirect_url = '/admin/login'

        if not request.user.is_authenticated() and request.path != redirect_url:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now, I realized that the issue is Chrome realizes there are too many redirects and kills everything.

Answer (score 6):

Additionaly, be sure you don't have this property to True in your Settings.py file

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

This works to me.