# Can't login as a user or admin in Django project even though password is right

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-admin

In the admin panel when my password is right and I click on login it just reloads me to the same page and when my password is wrong it shows an error and in my project when I log in it takes me to the home page but not logged in, but it used to work properly in starting.

My settings file

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!   
# SECRET_KEY = '4uo!kh!^)!lc^xb0!&4aym-=%2(guhdfr^!2ly+rb0_!=@qnhx'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', '4uo!kh!^)!lc^xb0!&4aym-=%2(guhdfr^!2ly+rb0_!=@qnhx')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#DEBUG = True
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') != 'False'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'locallibrary.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'locallibrary.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ''
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# The URL to use when referring to static files (where they will be served from)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

my URL file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='catalog/', permanent=True)),
    # to direct directly to catalog because we don't have any other app
 ]
 # for authentication
urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
# to add static files
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My admin file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author, Genre, Language, Book, BookInstance

# admin.site.register(BookInstance)
# admin.site.register(Book)
admin.site.register(Language)
# admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Genre)


class BooksInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book


# Define admin class list displayed so that when we have many author we can easily identify
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death')
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name' ,'image', ('date_of_birth', 'date_of_death')] # show in same row
    inlines = [BooksInline]


admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)


class BooksInstanceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BookInstance


# register the admin classes for Book Using the Decorator
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'display_genre')
    # can't directly specify the genre filed in list_display because it is ManyToManyField
    inlines = [BooksInstanceInline]

# Register the admin classes for BookInstance using the decorator
@admin.register(BookInstance)
class BookInstanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('book', 'status', 'borrower', 'due_back', 'id')
    list_filter = ('status', 'due_back') # list_filter will show option on side.
    fieldsets = (
        (None,{
            'fields': ('book', 'imprint', 'id')
        }),
        ('Availablity', {
            'fields': ('status', 'due_back', 'borrower')
        }),
    )
# Fieldsets None and Availability are titles, None because we don't want to give a title
```

** when I log in it shows status 302 and 301 on local server?
any suggestions what's wrong **

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the missing caret `^` in the URL configurations. A caret simply marks the beginning of line/string.

Change your patterns to the following and see if it solves it.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
    path(r'', RedirectView.as_view(url='catalog/', permanent=True)),
    # to direct directly to catalog because we don't have any other app
 ]
```

Also see the answer here if above doesn't work- [Redirect to /admin/login/ results in 302](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41840124/6505847)

Comment: still same probelm